# Как выделить родительский и дочерний раздел двухуровнего меню в битриксе, находясь в дочернем разделе

Tags: php, битрикс, backend

**Всем доброго времени суток.** У меня есть задание, дано многоуровневое меню (2 уровня), данные берутся из ИБ в файле .top.menu_ext.php и передаются в шаблон, где нужно интегрировать вывод пунктов меню в виде выпадающего списка.

Так же нужно сделать так, что при нахождении в родительском разделе он выделялся цветом. Если находимся в дочернем, то родительский выделяется вместе с дочерним разделом.

Я сделал файл result_modifer, в котором все дети родительского элемента записываются в подмассив CHILDREN, и все элементы этого подмассива позже выводятся в шаблоне, но не получается сделать правильно выделение. Выделяется только текущий раздел. При нахождении в дочернем элементе родительский не выделяется, а должен

**Ниже будет представлен код каждого файла или необходимый фрагмент**

***.top.menu_ext.php***

```html
<?php
if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();

use \Bitrix\Main\Data\Cache;
use \Bitrix\Main\Application;

global $APPLICATION;
$aMenuLinks = [];

$cache = Cache::createInstance();
$tag = Application::getInstance()->getTaggedCache();

if ($cache->initCache(3600, 'topMenu', 'catalog_top')) {

    $aMenuLinksExt = $cache->getVars();

} elseif ((CModule::IncludeModule('iblock')) && $cache->startDataCache()) {

    $tag->startTagCache('catalog_top');

    $arFilter = ["CODE" => "products"];
    $dbIBlock = CIBlock::GetList([], $arFilter);

    if ($arIBlock = $dbIBlock->GetNext()) {
        $aMenuLinksExt = $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
            "bitrix:menu.sections",
            "",
            [
                "IS_SEF" => "Y",
                "SECTION_PAGE_URL" => $arIBlock['SECTION_PAGE_URL'],
                "DETAIL_PAGE_URL" => $arIBlock['DETAIL_PAGE_URL'],
                "IBLOCK_TYPE" => $arIBlock['IBLOCK_TYPE'],
                "IBLOCK_ID" => $arIBlock['ID'],
                "DEPTH_LEVEL" => "2",
                "CACHE_TYPE" => "N",
            ],
        );
    }
    
    $tag->registerTag('iblock_id_' . $arIBlock['ID']);
    $tag->endTagCache();
    $cache->endDataCache($aMenuLinksExt);
}

$aMenuLinks = array_merge($aMenuLinks, $aMenuLinksExt);
```

***result_modifier.php***

```html
<?php

if (!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED !== true) die();

$arPrepItems = [];

if (!empty($arResult)) {
    foreach ($arResult as $item) {
        if ($item['DEPTH_LEVEL'] === 1) {
            $arPrepItems[] = $item;
        } else {
            $arPrepItems[end(array_keys($arPrepItems))]['CHILDREN'][] = $item;
        }
    }
}

$arResult = $arPrepItems;
```

***template.php***

```html
<?php if (!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED !== true) die(); ?>
<nav class="order-1">
    <ul class="block lg:flex">
        <?php foreach ($arResult as $arItem) : ?>  
        <li class="group">
            <?php if ($arItem['PARAMS']['DEPTH_LEVEL'] == 1) : ?>
                <a class="inline-block p-4 font-bold border-l border-r border-transparent <?= $arItem['SELECTED'] ? 'text-orange' : 'text-black' ?> hover:text-orange group-hover:bg-gray-100 group-hover:border-l group-hover:border-r group-hover:border-gray-200 group-hover:shadow" href="<?= $arItem['LINK'] ?>">
                    <?= $arItem['TEXT'] ?>
                    <?php if ($arItem['IS_PARENT']) : ?>
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="inline-block h-4 w-4" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M19 9l-7 7-7-7"></path>
                        </svg>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </a>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if (isset($arItem['CHILDREN'])) : ?>
                <ul class="dropdown-navigation-submenu absolute hidden group-hover:block bg-white shadow-lg">
                    <?php foreach ($arItem['CHILDREN'] as $child) : ?>
                        <li><a class="block py-2 px-4 <?= $child['SELECTED'] ? 'text-orange' : 'text-black' ?> hover:text-orange hover:bg-gray-100" href="<?= $child['LINK'] ?>"><?= $child['TEXT'] ?></a></li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

В родительском пункте меню нужно перечислить все ссылки дочерних пунктов меню. Примерно так:

```
$aMenuLinks = Array(
    Array(
        "Features",
        "/online-sales/",
        Array("/inventory/", "/sales/", "/service/", "/crm/", "/financials/", "/advertisers-portal/", "/security/"),
        Array("FROM_IBLOCK" => "1", "IS_PARENT" => "1", "DEPTH_LEVEL" => "1"),
        ""
    ),
...
);
```

Тогда в шаблоне $arItem['SELECTED'] будет true, если адрес страницы совпадает с одним из списка.

Comment: Нужно перечислить там ссылки всех детей, но массив CHILDREN тоже оставить?
У меня все данные из ИБ берутся, $aMenuLinks пустой. Но я попробую реализовать то, что вы предложили :)

Comment: Это нужно сделать в .top.menu_ext.php.

Comment: А почему там? Можете объяснить, пожалуйста, а то я не понимаю почему именно там :0

Comment: Потому что компонент меню берёт $aMenuLinks, смотрит, на какой странице находится, и строит $arResult, в котором выставляет свойство SELECTED. Этот $arResult уже передаётся в шаблон.